# Iterate through a DOM tree and put elements into a Json Object

Tags: jquery, json, list, loops, traversal

I have a multi level List in my HTML. I want to walk through the list and put the elements into a JSON Object.

For example i have this:

```
<ul id="list" class="list">
    <li class="listHead">
        First Header
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
        <ul class="list">
            <li class="listHead"> First SubHeader</li>
            <li class="listItem"> listItem1</li>
            <li class="listItem"> listItem2</li>
            <li class="listItem"> listItem3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">
        listItem4
    </li>
</ul>
```

Every list starts with a Header, that would be the current object's name.
So I want to convert the example above into something like this:

```
{
    "First Header": [{
        "First SubHeader": [
            "listItem": "listItem1",
            "listItem": "listItem2",
            "listItem": "listItem3"
        }
    ], {
        "listItem": "listItem4"
    }]
}
```

I would like to use JQuery and have tried to create a recursive DOM traversing function.

Comment: DOM structure is not very convenient to work with. I would expect different JSON output. For example check your HTML in [xml2json converter](http://dfsq.github.io/xml2json/#/xml/paste) (paste your HTML, uncheck "Include Attributes"). Not clear, why "First SubHeader" becomes a child of "First Header" in your desired JSON output.

Comment: Because the "First Header" is the Key of the first Json Object, and it represents the main list, as the "First SubHeader" represents the first sublist.